# Using colspan=2 in table cells with other cells without colspan i.e. colspan=1

Tags: html, html-table

I have come across with a problem regarding tables, to be more specific with the colspan attribute for the cells (td tag), I would like to do something like this:

```
*** ------- +++
------- *** +++
```

Where each symbol is a cell, as you might notice, the 2 column from the 1st row has a colspan=2 since is sharing it with the column number 1 and 2 from the 2nd row, meanwhile the 1st column from the row number 2 shares the space with the column number 1 and 2 from the 1st row.

I have tried (see code below), but of course (at least in chrome and in firefox) it doesn't work as expected. I think this is achievable but I am short of ideas and I will be really thankful for your suggestions.

```
<TABLE>
<TR>
    <TD>1</TD>
    <TD COLSPAN="2">2</TD>
    <TD>3</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
    <TD COLSPAN="2">4</TD>
    <TD>5</TD>
    <TD>6</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
```

Answer (score 0):

After some searching I have found the solution, it seems that you have to use the col tag, not sure why yet, but it works!

```
<TABLE>
<col style="width: 1px;">
<col style="width: 1px;">
<col style="width: 1px;">
<col style="width: 1px;">
<TBODY>
<TR>
    <TD BGCOLOR="#CDB599"></TD>
    <TD COLSPAN="2" BGCOLOR="#9CC5C9"></TD>
    <TD BGCOLOR="#CDB599"></TD>
</TR>
<TR>
    <TD COLSPAN="2" BGCOLOR="#D5544F"></TD>
    <TD BGCOLOR="#CDB599"></TD>
    <TD BGCOLOR="#CDB599"></TD>
</TR>
</TBODY>
</TABLE>
```

Comment: Hi Jukka, please take both codes (posted by me) and see the page, the first one will show a messed up table, the second will actually make the table that I wanted from the very beginning, I'm not sure how the col element solves this, I think that it allows to "understand" the browser that the table has 4 columns. I have tried without the style attribute giving me the messed table that I had in the very beginning. Please try both and please give me a feedback of what you think :) Cheers.

Comment: This is a question and answer system, not a discussion forum. You haven’t specified what you regard as a problem (what exactly “doesn’t work” in which sense).

Answer (score 0):

You don’t specify how you expect the markup to work, but the way it works is that slots in the second column are zero-width, as there is nothing that requires any minimum width for them. You can see this if you add a third row, with four normal cells:

```
<tr><td>foo<td>bar<td>more<td>stuff
```

Then the second column will take the width needed for “bar”.